# Deciding between signal-slot mechanism versus traditional loop

Tags: c++, qt, loops, signals-slots

I want to update many objects. I have the option to do so with traditional **loop** like:

```cpp
void ParentClass::updateItems(const float factor)
{
     for (Item *item : items()) {
        item->update(factor)
    }
}
```

... or I can do it with **signal-slot** mechanism like:

```cpp
class ParentClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

Q_SIGNALS:
    // The signal which will be emitted by parent:
    void updateNeeded(const float factor);

private:
    void updateItems(const float factor);
}

// Signal is emitted here
void ParentClass::updateItems(const float factor)
{
     emit updateNeeded(factor);
}


class Item : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Item(ParentClass *parent) : QObject()
    , m_parent(parent)
    {
        // Connect parent signal to each item slot at each item constructor
        QObject::connect(m_parent, &ParentClass::UpdateNeeded, 
                         this, &Item::handleUpdate);
    }

public Q_SLOTS:
    void handleUpdate(const float factor);

private:
    ParentClass *m_parent;
}


// The slot which handles emitted signal:
void Item::handleUpdate(const float factor)
{
    this->update(factor);
}
```

---

1. I have tested the **loop** approach and it works.
2. I'm thinking on **signal-slot** mechanism, maybe it has some benefits for complex code.
3. I wonder which approach is how it should be done or is there a better way?

---

After writing my question, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3007266/3405291) which is really helpful but I"m not sure if it is directly related to my question.

Comment: IMO the first approach is better: 1) It's simpler, 2) Avoids circular dependencies between classes.

Comment: No one asked how many `items()` there are. What does `update(factor)` actually do (eg. is it a complex operation)? Is this running in GUI thread? W/out more details this looks a lot like an opinion question to my eyes.

Comment: @MaximPaperno Thanks for mentioning a benefit of signal-slot approach regarding **GUI responsiveness**.

Comment: I think both answers provided in this question could be useful in general terms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919309/call-function-directly-vs-emiting-signal-qt-signals-and-slots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the loop based approach whenever and whereever you can, KISS

**signal-slot** is a very loose-coupled method of interfacing - while this can be great sometimes (mostly when other options are not possible..) it is much more *brittle* than regular function calls.

Comment: I went with the **loop** approach =)

Comment: Whoa... nice opinion. Anything to back up these statements about loose coupling and being brittle? Loops in GUI thread (if that is what we see here) isn't necessarily a great approach, regardless of how KISS it looks. It could block the UI for example, depending on what the `update()` method actually does. How many `items()` are there? Using signals/slots, perhaps even queued ones, could make a big difference in app responsiveness.  IMHO.  :)

Comment: @MaximPaperno App responsiveness is a concern - but signal-slot isn't needed at all for solving that.

Comment: Queued connections can certainly make a big difference in GUI responsiveness, even if everything runs in the same thread. Otherwise, what... `QCoreApplication::processEvents()` inside the loop?  blech.  Still would like to see what "loose-coupled" and "brittle" mean.

Comment: @MaximPaperno using signal slot mechanism instead of direct calling is a form of over-engineering - unless theres a real reason to use. The loosely coupled (and to some extent brittle) comes from mess that you can create out of it. N objects 'signaling' some M objects. And if you remove a connect call theres no compiler error, etc., etc. to help you.

Comment: "... unless theres a real reason to use" -- Agreed, and that's pretty much my point is that from the question there's no clue what is the "best" approach here. Sure the loop looks much simpler and cleaner in the given code snippet. I also wonder about "Use the loop based approach whenever and whereever you can" which IMHO will also depend on what exactly the loop is doing -- as mentioned elsewhere there are plenty of opinions online about loops to the contrary. As for messes... there's a zillion ways to mess up code. E.g. the compiler won't warn you if an `item` was never added to `items()`.